# How to insert in to a table from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables employee and time_stamp
each employee has his hex and emp_id 
and i want to insert into time_stamp table the time the hex that will come from the time stamping machine and the emp_id from the employee table...
this is my query ..

```
INSERT INTO time_stamp (hex,time,emp_id)
              SELECT emp_id  ({$hex}, NOW() )
              FROM employee
              WHERE hex = {$hex}
```

and thats what I get as an error:

```
FUNCTION junicom.emp_id does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing...

```
INSERT INTO time_stamp (hex,time,emp_id)
SELECT hex, NOW(), emp_id
FROM employee
WHERE hex = '$hex'
```

Comment: Bohemian - selective OCD? ;-)